# How to draw a rectangle on a WPF canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm trying to draw a `Rectangle` on a `Canvas` as follows:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect;
rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
rect.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
rect.Width=200;
rect.Height=200;
Canvas.SetLeft(rect,0);
Canvas.SetTop(rect,0);
front_canvas.Children.Add(rect);
```

Why would this code not draw a rectangle?

The canvas is defined in the associated XAML as follows:

```
<Canvas Height="200" Width="200" Name="front_canvas" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">      
</Canvas>
```

The canvas shows up fine. I can tell because of the gap it leaves in the layout grid.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I can tell it is not squished because there is a big gap where the canvas should be and nothing else could be causing it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should draw your rectangle as a 200x200 black square, provided `front_canvas` is displayed correctly.

> Why would this code not draw a rectangle?

The main reasons this would not draw are:

- `front_canvas` is not visible
- `front_canvas` is not in the visual tree and being displayed correctly
- Some other `FrameworkElement` is  obscuring `front_canvas`, at least the upper left corner.
- There is another object in the canvas at a higher z order.

Note that you'd typically also want to set [`StrokeThickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.strokethickness%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) if you want to see the `Stroke` you specify.

Answer (score 2):

To View Rectangle you must specify the `StrokeThickness` and set any `Integer` value greater than zero:

```
rect.StrokeThickness=2;
```

Comment: or a Fill/Background, or (...). But this is still a good hint for people new to drawing, as they often forget that white shape on a white background is not visible despite being drawn/rendered correctly;)